# To link in CodeIgniter within application

Tags: codeigniter

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url ('welcome/aboutus');?> "> About Us </a>
```

Here **welcome** is controller name  and **aboutus** is page name. I have set autoload. If I run this then it shows "Object not Found", what's wrong with that?

Comment: Add some code and explain better what's wrong with this

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit hard to help you with because you have limited code to go by.

You may need to set your base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Welcome is the controller name as you said and aboutus would be a function name

Follow the PHP Codeigniter Naming [Style Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming)

Welcome.php

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {

}

public function aboutus() {

}

}
```

You may need a suitable [.htaccess file](https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter) to remove it so can work with out index.php

```
application

system

.htaccess

index.php
```

Try with `<?php echo base_url ('index.php/welcome/aboutus');?>`

Answer (score 1):

In CodeIgniter, it dose not work like that.

```
<?php base_url ('welcome/aboutus') ?>
```

What it means is that **Welcome** is the name of the **controller** and ***aboutus*** is the name of the function in the controller.

So when you click on the link generated by the above code, it will search for a function named ***aboutus*** in the controller file **Welcome**.

To load about us using your link, the controller should look like this,

```
<?php

  class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {}

    public function aboutus() {
     $this->load->view('Name of the view file');
    }
  } ?>
```

I think you should know **What is MVC Framework?** and **How Dose it Work?**.

Have a look at these::

[CI MVC Framework](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/overview/mvc.html)

[CI MVC Static Page](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/static_pages.html)